# How to convert Lon Lat to Geomtry in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

Now. I had Lon Lat. I want convert Lon Lat to Geomtry in Openlayers. But i don't know. 
Ex my problem:
I want convert 106.62639994087715 11.00448399644145 [LON LAT] to **0101000020E61000002812C7EF16A85A409024F4B94B022640**[GEOMTRY]
Please help me. Tks all.

Answer (score 2):

If your map is displaying in 4326 projection (Lat, Long) then just use new Point([Long,Lat]) to create a point geometry 
Otherwise you should convert Lat/Long to a certain projection using ol/proj.fromLonLat([Long, Lat], )
see [official docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.fromLonLat)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want, you can get a geometry (Point in your case) like this :

```
new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
```

The `ol.proj.transform` is used to convert the coordinates because generally a webmap uses `EPSG:3857` while lat/long are in `ESPG:4326`.

Comment: Tks u. Ex my problem: convert 106.62639994087715 11.00448399644145 to 0101000020E61000002812C7EF16A85A409024F4B94B022640

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is to get binary representation of geometry you found in database. I don't think it is possible to achieve that in OpenLayers, and I don't think that you need that. You could get result you want if you execute this in PostgreSQL/PostGIS:
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(106.62639994087715 11.00448399644145)', 4326);